# how to write vertical vectors in plain TeX

Tags: vertical-alignment

I would like to right a column vector in plain TeX without using the `\matrix` command (it seems too wide otherwise). How can I do it?

Comment: $$\left[\vbox{\hbox{$a_1$}\hbox{$a_2$}}\right]$$

Comment: Or maybe `$${a_1\brack a_2}$$`?

Comment: I see nothing strange in the minimal example `$$\left[\matrix{a\cr b\cr c\cr d}\right]$$\bye` Can you add some more information?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Did you try? I guess not, or you'd have discovered that it does something not really expected.

Comment: If you mean the extra space at the bottom?  I don't remember    \vbox doing that back in my plain TeX days.  I suspect it has to do with    \usepackage{plain}.

Comment: I meant on "the sides": The round brackets \left( and \right) seem too "curvy" or "wide". Say you want a vector (x,x-5, z), but vertical. They seem a bit "too curved".

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming that by wide you mean the spacing between the delimiters and inner content.

`\matrix` is defined with a `\thinmuskip` (that is, by default, `3 mu`) around it with the macro `\,`.

Here's its definition in full:

```
\def\matrix#1{\null\,\vcenter{\normalbaselines\m@th
    \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
      \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
      #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}\,}
```

So you could make your own `\tightmatrix` by just copying the above without the `\,`'s, for example:

```
\def\tightmatrix#1{\null\vcenter{\normalbaselines\mathsurround=0pt
  \ialign{\hfil$##$\hfil&&\quad\hfil$##$\hfil\crcr
    \mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}
    #1\crcr\mathstrut\crcr\noalign{\kern-\baselineskip}}}}
\def\bmatrix#1{\left[\tightmatrix{#1}\right]}

$$ A \left[ \matrix{a_1\cr a_2} \right] B $$
$$ A \bmatrix{a_1\cr a_2} B $$ % can have more than two rows
$$ A {a_1\atopwithdelims[] a_2} B $$ % aka \brack only two rows
\bye
```

One could perhaps consider wrapping the `\vcenter` inside a `\mathinner`.

Here's a comparison:

[image]

I like the overall spacing of the last one best, but for more than two rows, you need to start adding style changes and grouping, and it gets really messy really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my corrected answer with a LaTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{plain}
\begin{document}
\begin{plain}
$$\left[\vcenter{\hbox{$\mathstrut a_1$}\hbox{$\mathstrut a_2$}}\right]$$
\end{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image: colunmn vector]